# Magento 2 - "Starting at" does not show lowest price

Tags: magento2, product, category, grouped-products, tierprice

This is a group product with tier prices in our shop. As you can see, the lowest possible price is 151,20 €.

[image]

But in the category view it shows 167,20 € instead of 151,20 €

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you will have trouble with price filtering too

Answer (score 1):

To check the tier price of any product, you can use the following code in the conditions :

```
<?php
$tierprices = array();
if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped'){
    $associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($associatedProducts as $assoc_product) {
    //$assoc_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($assoc_product->getId());// use this only if necessary
        if($assoc_product->getTierPrice()){
            $product_tier_prices = $this->getTierPrices($assoc_product);
            if(count($product_tier_prices) > 0){
                $product_tier_prices = (object)$product_tier_prices;
                foreach($product_tier_prices as $key=>$value){
                    $value = (object)$value;
                    $tierprices[] = $value->price;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
} ?>
```

In this way you will get tier prices of all the associated products of Group product. You need to use the following condition to display "minimum tier" or "as low as":

```
<?php if(count($tierprices) > 0){ ?>
    <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
        <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency(min($tierprices), true, false) ?>
    </span>

<?php } else { ?>
all your rest of normal price will come here.
<?php } ?>
```

And more information Check link :-

**https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/5kxvbc/always_show_lowest_price_for_grouped_product_with/**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...

Comment: Your answer is about Magento 1, not 2 ...